# ASP.NET Core async API Controller returns ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

This code:

```
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_strConn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sometable FOR JSON AUTO";
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            await Response.WriteAsync(reader[0].ToString());
                        }

                        await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Works just fine until I get to the client.  In Chrome I get an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on the connection that is calling this api controller method.  The response is valid but the socket close seems to be the issue.  The data has been sent down the wire.

I have tried returning multiple different ActionResults from this function to close the connection properly to no avail.

At this point I have resorted to loading the entire response into memory and returning a JsonResult which works as expected but I now become a monstrous memory consumer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  Also, if not, could you please update the OP so that it includes the complete public action method (with function definition)?